# How to print a statement while the user is giving input?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am making a code which is similar to a video game chat.
Here is a sample code I wrote just for this questions

```
import threading

def printOtherUsersMsg():
   print("User: hiii")

def takeInput():
   msg = input("Msg: ")
   print(msg)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=takeInput)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=printOtherUsersMsg)
thread2.start()
```

What happens now is that in the output the users input line is over written by the print statement in the other thread, any idea how I can prevent this?

output-

```
Msg: User: hiii
vndfv
vndfv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your processes are not independent: you require a certain order in those outputs.  Therefore, you need you synchronize them with one bit of inter-process communication.  A simple condition will suffice.

```
def printOtherUsersMsg(flag):
    print("User: hiii")
    flag.notify()

def takeInput(flag):
    flag.wait()
    msg = input("Msg: ")
    print(msg)

flag = threading.Condition
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=takeInput, args=(flag))
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=printOtherUserMsg, args=(flag))
thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just flip your targets.

**flipped**

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=printOtherUsersMsg)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=takeInput)
thread2.start()
```

**output**

```
User: hiii
Msg: hey
hey
```

Comment: but my original code is much bigger, I used a server and a clients, the clients can send messages whenever they want, so that overrides the input statement.